# Can tag synonyms can be removed or deleted?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

If we find a tag synonym that is incorrect, does anyone have the privilege to remove or delete it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, ♦ moderators have the ability to remove tag synonyms.  If you see one that should be removed you can post a question tagged `discussion` and `tag-synonyms` here on Meta so the community can weigh in on it before an action is taken.

Comment: But, after that, some manual retagging might be needed? If I understand correctly, then the tag that was selected by a user [might be lost](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/507574#507574) if it is a synonym?

Comment: @Arjan: Yes, some retagging is needed, particularly when a synonym is removed.  When a new synonym is created we can use the mass retag tool to make all the questions affected have the same tag.  If a synonym is reversed we can do the same.  Unfortunately it's not as easy when one is just removed.

Comment: Can pro-tempora moderators remove tag synonyms?