# How can tag synonyms be remapped or unmapped?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

Currently, [cfml](/questions/tagged/cfml) is a synonym for [coldfusion](/questions/tagged/coldfusion). ColdFusion (sold by Adobe), Railo, and OpenBlue Dragon (among others) all parse/interpret/etc "CFML", which is an [acronym](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/add-support-for-abbr-tag) for "Cold Fusion Markup Language".

Is it possible to remove the synonym of CFML to ColdFusion?

Comment: I knows nothing about ColdFusion. Nevertheless, can you explain why there is a need to differentiate them?

Comment: @nhahtdh Because cfml can be handled by Railo and OpenBlue Dragon as well, so it's not unique to CF.

Comment: @Jack: Lol, really need to get some sleep...

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the power to do anything about it, so here's an upvote :)

Comment: I think this synonym is still valid. There are tags for the other CFML engines yet most users still tag the question as "ColdFusion". While `CFML` is technically not `ColdFusion` I don't see how removing the synonym would benefit anyone as CFML specific questions should be tagged as the correct engine, ie Railo, BlueDragon

Comment: ColdFusion represents a subset of the CFML "universe". Plenty of CFML language questions aren't confined to just one engine, and we shouldn't want SO taxonomy to imply the primacy of one engine over an alternative.‡ I think there's justification for all the tags to exist. ‡-I am not affiliated with any of these engines and have received no compensation for my opinions on this subject!

Comment: I'm undecided on this, but I think leaning towards removing the synonym ... will put more detail in an answer.

Comment: Not knowing that the synonym *replaced* the original tag, I agree. Being that the synonym replaces the original tag I **can not** say in good faith that `most users still tag the question as "ColdFusion"` as I did above.  +1

Comment: That would also mean the cfscript synonym is invalid as well.

Comment: Check out the last line of the BlueDragon tag excerpt: http://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/57400

Comment: And Railo's: http://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/19829

Comment: I've asked for a moderator to take a peak at this. Meanwhile, I propose the following: remove CFML synonym association with ColdFusion. Establish CFML tag. Repoint CF/CFSCRIPT synonyms from ColdFusion to CFML. Sound good to all? Should I start a new "question" for this activity? (I'm not trying to be a rep wh*re)

Comment: @JeromyFrench I removed the [tag:cfml]->[tag:coldfusion] synonym and created the cf->cfml and cfscript->cfml synonyms. You might want to create a decent tag wiki for [tag:cfml] now, and maybe retag some older questions (though this isn't strictly necessary).

Comment: @AnnaLear: much appreciated.

Comment: If you are going to suggest edits that add this tag, please take care of the rest of the post issues at the same time. Remove thankyou, fix the grammar and spelling, fix formatting issues etc. Otherwise the edit is too minor.

Comment: @KateGregory: Happy to do so, but proper categorization isn't too minor.

Comment: It is if it requires review. If you have full edit privs go ahead and just retag, but if someone has to look it over, take care of everything.

Comment: @KateGregory: Hmm. It seems to me that there used to be a way to edit the tags outside the posting edit process; a way that wouldn't clutter the review queu. Don't know why that's no longer the case--or maybe I'm not seeing the link to that mechanism? *Still*, propoer taxonomy is just as worthwhile as correct grammar.

Comment: @KateGregory: in any case, I've got a few free moments, and I'm just trying to help the cause by targeting a specific ill (posts that accidentally use ColdFusion as a blanket term for CFML). Hopefully if I can correct enough recent posts it'll establish a precedent and the correct-tagging practice will catch-on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86063/can-tag-synonyms-can-be-removed-or-deleted?rq=1), yes. the question must be tagged with [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms) to be seen and discussed by the community.

Comment: Well I added discussion tag. Not sure if I should have removed the support tag when doing that or not, but I guess someone will correct that if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

When I originally suggested the synonym, it was a combination of pragmatism and misunderstanding of how synonyms worked.

At the time, Railo was still generally considered an "alternative" to CF -- rather than a solution in its own right, which it is now, (or at least is tending towards) -- and I don't know that it was possible to easily monitor multiple tags, so it made sense to have the already most common "coldfusion" tag as the main one, since that's what most people used.

I also thought the tags would simply pointed/aliased to each other rather than be replaced, so the original tag would still be visible.

Given the way tags actually work, that it is easy to combine tags in search/bookmarks, and that Railo is more and more its own thing, I think I'm in favour of removing the synonym, so cfml can be a standalone engine-agnostic/parent/overall tag.

There's still a part of me saying that the masses will still just use/look at [coldfusion], and this would simply be extra work for those of us that monitor/fix CFML questions, but in general I prefer doing things correctly and educating as necessary, rather than dumbing down for the lowest common denominator.

---

A quick note for the uninitiated, a rough comparison is:

```
C#             <-> CFML
Microsoft .NET <-> Adobe ColdFusion
Mono           <-> Railo
```

It's not a perfect analogy, but hopefully gives an idea...

Comment: `I also thought the tags would simply pointed/aliased to each other rather than be replaced, so the original tag would still be visible.` I didn't realize that until just now either so yeah, I agree.

Comment: @PeterBoughton: we sure have crossed paths alot in the past 12 hours! Gratitude for your participation and thoughts...

Comment: That said, none of us are answering the question: *can* synonyms be un/re-mapped? How?

Comment: It's been [done before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103634/please-remove-the-c11-tag-synonym), so guess it's a question of waiting for an admin to see it.

Comment: Late to the party... I'm not sure where I am on this one. Perhaps the tags are backwards.  Maybe CFML should be the base tag and ColdFusion, Railo and BlueDragon should be synonyms for it?  Unless, like you say, the synonyms are not an alias but actually replace the original tag.  Is that correct?

Comment: Doing that would mean not being able to tell what engine is being used by tags. They need to stay Disassociated

Comment: I guess I don't understand how the synonyms work then. I will trust you guys and go ahead and upvote this as well.

Comment: The tag synonym functionality is as a way to have a single canonical tag, and remap common variants to that canonical one. It does not deal with related aliases or parent/child, so (at the moment) if you tag a question with [tag:cfml] [tag:cfscript] the result is a single [tag:coldfusion] (due to both of the former being synoynms of the latter) which is losing information that may be relevant. If CF/Railo/BD tags were synonymed to CFML, a similar change/loss would happen.

Comment: Ok, I see. I always tag things with ColdFusion so I did not realize that if you used the other tags, cfml cfscript, then it would change the tag to ColdFusion. Thanks for the explanation. And now I agree with you guys.